# Use of 'self' in method call 'f' before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: swift

The A:f() just print *HeHe* and it doesn't take any use of properties(, in this case there is just one: a.) or any 'self'-thing as the compiler pointed out. So I wonder whether the compiler means self.f()?

```
class A {
    var a: String
    init(a: String) {
        f()
        self.a = a
    }

    func f() {
        print("HeHe")
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
PlayGround.playground:4:9: error: use of 'self' in method call 'f' before all stored properties are initialized
    f()
    ^
```

Comment: just call `f()` after initializing all your class properties. In this case after `self.a = a`

Comment: My problem is about I'm not using `self` in method `f()`, the link doesn't solve my problem. @ShamasS

Comment: @user7813604: If `f()` does does not use any properties of `self` then you can make it a class method (which is one of the solutions proposed in the first duplicate). Also have a look at the "Related" section, there are some more Q&As about the very same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean that if you haven't written `self` with function call `f` then it will not reference to `self` as of `f` is still instance method, so with `init` it must be called after all the instance properties are initialized means after the the instance of class is initialized. So simply call `f()` after you `initialized` the instance property `a`.

```
class A {
    var a: String
    init(a: String) {
        self.a = a
        f()
    }

    func f() {
        print("HeHe")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every stored property must be initialized (default values or with init's) before the struct or class can be used. Period. You are calling a class method before the class is initialised. Even if that method does not use or access a class property.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty agreed with your absolutely right concept. But this means the error message is misleading.

Comment: If the `f()` in init() is a shorthand of `self.f()`, then ok, compiler is right.